# Combining eval() and return in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, pickle, fast-ai

I'm trying to use a function to iteratively return several machine learning models (pickles) with a function based on the accuracy cutoff I specify.

My issue is that I'm trying to load the pickles with eval, as their names correspond to the number given by sdf['number']. The eval function is not loading my pickles, and beyond that, I want them to be loaded and returned by my function. I have tested this by attempting to directly run data through each model after loading it before it moves on to the next one, but it is returning "learn0 not defined" for example.

Any thoughts on how to better do this iteratively?

> Variables Explained:
>
> jar = A list of the different variable names (learner names) that I
> expected it to load. For example, learn0, learn1, etc.
>
> cutoff = Accuracy Cutoff
>
> sdf_temp = Temporary Study DataFrame

```
def piklJar(sdf,cutoff):
    sdf_temp = sdf[sdf['value'] <= cutoff]
    
    jar = []
    i=0
    for pklNum in sdf_temp['number']:
        eval('"learn{} = load_learner({}/Models/Pkl {}.pkl)".format(i,datapath,pklNum)')
        jar.append('learn{}'.format(i))
        
        i+=1
        
    return jar
```

Comment: Using `eval` here makes no sense. Unless you are doing some serious metaprogramming or actually need the python interpreter (e.g. programming a repl) then you pretty much never need eval, and it is pretty much never a good solution

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Any suggestions for a replacement?

Comment: @En_g_neer your `jar` variable here would just be a list of strings since you're appending a string not the variable. Since you're returning a list, assigning unique variable names is useless

Comment: correct, @MZ, I was intending to return the list of strings as well so I had a list for reference of all the learners I was loading. Luckily Mark solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` isn't needed.  Your example wasn't working code, but this is approximately the same thing:

```
def piklJar(sdf,cutoff):
    sdf_temp = sdf[sdf['value'] <= cutoff]
    return [load_learner(f'{datapath}/Models/Pkl {pklNum}') for pklNum in sdf_temp['number']]
```

After calling `jar = pklJar(...)`, `jar[0]` would be equivalent to `learn0`, `jar[1]` would be `learn1`, etc.  The various `load_learner` calls are stored in a list generated from a list comprehension.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Mark. I believe this solved my problem. I just assigned x = piklJar(blabla,blabla) and it appears to have stored my models in x as a list.